"SWAPBASEIN" vs. "SWAP" transactions
I see that A LOT of tokens have these "SWAPBASEIN" transactions righ after the token mint and often  before pool creation. Also, almost all of those transactions fail.
I would really appreciate if someone could explain what is going on there? And, what is the difference between SWAP and SWAPBASEIN transaction types.
(My best guess is that those are sniper bots which are (for some reason) triggered by token mint instead of pool creation.)
Many thakns!
